# Werid ClassCastException in TreeMap.containsKey()

Tags: java, android, json, gson, classcastexception

This is the line where crash occurs

```
offsetDuration = duration - (offsets.containsKey(freq) 
                    ? offsets.get(freq) : 0l);
```

The values I got by catching the `Exception` and dumping the variables,

```
long offsetDuration = 0;
long duration = 391144;
TreeMap<Long, Long> offsets = {0=4024974.0, 1036800=8588.0, 1190400=88216.0, 1267200=49763.0, 1497600=87476.0, 1574400=7469.0, 1728000=54553.0, 1958400=60512.0, 2265600=246942.0, 300000=390779.0, 422400=39945.0, 652800=55204.0, 729600=46829.0, 883200=19191.0, 960000=23888.0}
long freq = 300000;
```

The variable `TreeMap<Long, Long> offsets` is parsed from a json file by using the code below.

```
@NonNull
public static TreeMap<Long, Long>  getOffsets(Context context) throws CpuStateException {
    File file = getOffsetsFile(context);
    TreeMap<Long, Long> map;

    try {
        String s = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8).trim();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<Long, Long>>(){}.getType();
        map = gson.fromJson(s, type);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CpuStateException("Failed to read offsets!");
    }

    if (map == null)
        throw new CpuStateException("Failed to read offsets!");

    return map;
}
```

After examining the code many times, I can't identify a situation where this code can throw a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at java.lang.Long.compareTo(Long.java:32)
    at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java:277)
    at java.util.TreeMap.findByObject(TreeMap.java:351)
    at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:182)
    at com.vibhinna.library.engine.CpuStates.getCpuData(CpuStates.java:96)
    at com.vibhinna.library.engine.CpuStates.getBarData(CpuStates.java:162)
```

Any ideas?

Updates 1: this is how the json is generated:

```
public static void offsetTimers(TreeMap<Long, Long> offsets, Context context) throws CpuStateException {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(offsets);
    File file = getOffsetsFile(context);

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),
                "UTF-8");
        outputStream.write(json);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CpuStateException("Failed to save offsets!");
    }
}
```

**Update 2** : I am not even able to reproduce this even in the original app, the crash is rare and reported by about only in less than 1% of clients.

**Update 3**

```
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1036800
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1190400
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1267200
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1497600
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1574400
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1728000
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 1958400
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 2265600
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 300000
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 422400
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 652800
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 729600
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 883200
offset class: class java.lang.String    value: 960000
```

**json:**

```
{  
   "0":256093,
   "300000":105045,
   "422400":9677,
   "652800":10443,
   "729600":8868,
   "883200":3951,
   "960000":7323,
   "1036800":18668,
   "1190400":34938,
   "1267200":17151,
   "1497600":11018,
   "1574400":1173,
   "1728000":22881,
   "1958400":21076,
   "2265600":66501
}
```

Comment: Please post the original JSON... are you able to reproduce this in a short but complete desktop app?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not even able to reproduce this even in the original app, the crash is rare and reported by about only in less than 1% of clients.

Comment: It would be worth putting that information in the question then. I assume that means you don't know the JSON that caused this?

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I don't have the json file, but I have added the code that generated the json, moreover you can get an idea as to what the json was by looking at the `TreeMap<Long, Long> offsets = {0=4024974.0, 1036800=8588.0, 1190400=88216.0, 1267200=49763.0, 1497600=87476.0, 1574400=7469.0, 1728000=54553.0, 1958400=60512.0, 2265600=246942.0, 300000=390779.0, 422400=39945.0, 652800=55204.0, 729600=46829.0, 883200=19191.0, 960000=23888.0}` . It was generated by the the toString method of TreeMap offsets, which was parsed from the json.

Comment: Well that's *one* sample of the JSON. Just to try reproducing this, try specifying a really *huge* `long` value which can't be exactly represented as a `double`... 9223372036854775806 would do. See what JSON that produces, and what happens when you parse it.

Comment: @BinoyBabu In the output `300000=390779.0` you cannot see whether the key and the value are really of type `Long` or `String`. Maybe the original JSON indeed contained a string?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I'll write a test for that. By the way, as you can see from the data dump I made during the crash, json parsing was more or less successful. The crash seems to be caused by some weird change in the Type of the key of the TreeMap even though I had specified TreeMap<Long, Long>. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, the data dump doesn't show the actual type. I wouldn't like to speculate on what's happened until we can reproduce it. But the fact that you've got values of `8588.0` show that they're not all actually `Long`...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose My thoughts exactly. But then the method signature `TreeMap<Long, Long>  getOffsets(Context context)` should ensure that I'm getting a `TreeMap<Long, Long>` right?

Comment: Off topic for this question but your resource handling is poor; you'll get at least an fd leak.

Comment: @JonSkeet But the method signature TreeMap<Long, Long> getOffsets(Context context) should mean that I'm getting a TreeMap<Long, Long> right?

Comment: Well, Java generics can lie somewhat. That's why it's all quite fiddly. With unsafe casts, you can easily end up with the wrong data in a map...

Comment: @BinoyBabu Well, no! Generics use the so called [_type erasure_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure). So, with some casts and/or raw type usages you could put whatever you want into a `Map<Long, Long>`. And this maybe happens while parsing a JSON that does not contain all longs.

Comment: The stack trace indicates that a java.lang.String object is being passed down from `CpuStates.getCpuData(CpuStates.java:96)`. I think you need to  find out where that object is coming from.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose A bug in Gson perhaps?

Comment: I would say that your code is wrong. Jon Skeet already told you that the number `8588.0` for example isn't a long value, yet you are putting it into a `Map<Long, Long>`. The same might happen to the keys. Find out what JSON causes the problem and then correct your code accordingly.

Comment: @SteveC Yes, the stack trace says a string gets passed in offsets.containsKey(freq). But the actually I can certify that freq is a Long. `freq = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));` and it's value during the crash is `300000`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I see, but that's a misunderstanding, I dont have the actual json file involved in the crash. `8588.0` was generated by calling `TreeMap.toString()` on the `TreeMap<Long, Long> offsets`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can confirm that I'm ending up with the wrong data in the map when the crash occurs. See the output off `offsets.tostring()` in a normal case `offsets: {0=581709, 250000=66717, 300000=31446, 350000=633, 400000=862, 450000=932, 500000=1240, 550000=970, 600000=36148, 800000=6947, 900000=1125, 1000000=1539, 1100000=1282, 1200000=6729, 1300000=648, 1400000=4768, 1500000=433, 1600000=17417}` contrast with the earlier output.

Comment: Right. At this point, it's probably hard for us to help you much more - you probably want to check what the devices which are failing have in common - check version numbers of everything you can find, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand. I have found no such patterns so far.

Comment: What version of Gson are you using?

Comment: Can you add to your exception catch variable dump (raw types on purpose) `Iterator iter = offset.keySet(); while(iter.hasNext()) { Object next = iter.next(); log("offset class: " + next.getClass() + "\tvalue: " + next); }` It doesn't matter the key you're finding, the problem is the map itself is polluted by a String somehow.

Comment: @duron597 I'll add it to the crash dump and ping you when a user reports. Version is 2.3.1

Comment: @JonSkeet I have managed to create a workaround (see below). Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Hi, I have made a workaround(see below). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have procured the json file

Comment: @durron597 I have updated the question with the data you wnated

Comment: But you still can't reproduce it locally?

Comment: @JonSkeet sadly, no. It's device specific. Maybe related to some specific dalvik/art version. But the crash occurs in android 4.4, 5.0 and 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the ugly workaround that seems to be working.

```
@NonNull
public static TreeMap<Long, Long>  getOffsets(Context context) throws CpuStateException {
    File file = getOffsetsFile(context);
    TreeMap map;

    try {
        String s = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8).trim();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<Long, Long>>(){}.getType();
        map = gson.fromJson(s, type);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CpuStateException("Failed to read offsets!");
    }

    if (map == null)
        throw new CpuStateException("Failed to read offsets!");

    // So, I don't trust Gson. On some devices the above code seems to be producing a
    // TreeMap<String, Double/Float>. So let's assume it's either a String or a boxed primitive.
    // Even if the assumption is wrong we're no worse off than we were before.
    // The String we'll parse, the primitive we'll cast. Brace yourselves for a horrible hack!
    // TODO find a proper fix.
    Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();
    TreeMap<Long, Long> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object key = it.next();
        Object value = map.get(key);
        Long lKey, lValue;

        if ((key instanceof Long)) {
            lKey = (Long) key;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key type in TreeMap: " + key.getClass());
            if (key instanceof Number) {
                lKey = ((Number) key).longValue();
            } else if (key instanceof String) {
                lKey = Double.valueOf((String) key).longValue();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key in TreeMap: "  + key);
            }
        }

        if ((value instanceof Long)) {
            lValue = (Long) value;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid value type in TreeMap: " + value.getClass());
            if (value instanceof Number) {
                lValue = ((Number) value).longValue();
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                lValue = Double.valueOf((String) value).longValue();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value in TreeMap: " + value);
            }
        }
        treeMap.put(lKey, lValue);
    }

    return treeMap;
}
```

Comment: Of course this works, but it doesn't solve the real problem. Your heap is still getting corrupted and you don't know why. What version of android is this?

Comment: @durron597 No, it doesn't. Do you think it's a problem in Gson?

Comment: No; I looked at the Gson source pretty thoroughly today and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @durron597 ART/Dalvik then?

Comment: @durron597 No. I have an alpha tester whose device seems to be consistently giving the same aberrant output. Do you want me to get this output since the fix confirms our suspicions?

Comment: I do want to know which String in particular is breaking, yes.

Comment: @durron597 I think all elements are breaking, since `300000` would be the first one to be iterated. I'll release another alpha with the fix disabled.

Comment: @durron597 Further evidence everything breaks is the toString() outputs like `155204.0`, which are not expected from a `Long`. These appears on all elements.

Comment: Can you change the **serializer** to use `gson.toJson(offsets, new TypeToken<TreeMap<Long, Long>(){}.getType());`

Comment: @durron597 I've added that. It'll be I while before I can get a result. Thanks.

Comment: Well make sure that version is logging the error, your fix doesn't appear have code to track future problems

Comment: @durron597 Thanks, I'll add that.